# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 65534-65535: unexpected end of data

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption

I want to encrypt file with simple  AES encryption,here is my python3 source code.

```
import os, random, struct
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

def encrypt_file(key, in_filename, out_filename=None, chunksize=64*1024):
    if not out_filename:
        out_filename = in_filename + '.enc'
    iv = os.urandom(16)
    encryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    filesize = os.path.getsize(in_filename)
    with open(in_filename, 'rb') as infile:
        with open(out_filename, 'wb') as outfile:
            outfile.write(struct.pack('<Q', filesize))
            outfile.write(iv)
            while True:
                chunk = infile.read(chunksize)
                if len(chunk) == 0:
                    break
                elif len(chunk) % 16 != 0:
                    chunk += ' ' * (16 - len(chunk) % 16)
                outfile.write(encryptor.encrypt(chunk.decode('UTF-8','strict')))
```

It works fine for some files,encounter error info for some files such as below:

> > > encrypt_file("qwertyqwertyqwer",'/tmp/test1' , out_filename=None, chunksize=64*1024)

No error info,works fine.

> > > encrypt_file("qwertyqwertyqwer",'/tmp/test2' , out_filename=None, chunksize=64*1024)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 17, in encrypt_file
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 65534-65535: unexpected end of data
```

How to fix my encrypt_file function?

Do as `t.m.adam` say ,to fix

```
outfile.write(encryptor.encrypt(chunk.decode('UTF-8','strict')))
```

as

```
outfile.write(encryptor.encrypt(chunk))
```

To try with some file.

```
encrypt_file("qwertyqwertyqwer",'/tmp/test' , out_filename=None, chunksize=64*1024)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 16, in encrypt_file
TypeError: can't concat bytes to str
```

Comment: Why are you decoding your data? `.encrypt()` can handle bytes, in fact, with Python3, it will raise an exception if you pass a string.

Comment: TypeError: can't concat bytes to str

Comment: would you give me the whole python encrypt_file function?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The main issue with your code is that you're using strings. AES works with binary data, and if you were using PyCryptodome this code   would raise a TypeError:

```
Object type <class 'str'> cannot be passed to C code
```

Pycrypto accepts strings, but encodes them to bytes internally, so it doesn't make sense to decode your bytes to string because it will be encoded back to bytes. Also, it encodes with ASCII (tested with PyCrypto v2.6.1, Python v2.7) and so, this code for example:

```
encryptor.encrypt(u'ψ' * 16)
```

would raise a UnicodeEncodeError:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\blockalgo.py", line 244, in encrypt
    return self._cipher.encrypt(plaintext)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-15
```

You should always use bytes when encrypting or decrypting data. Then you can decode the plaintext to string, if it is text.

The next issue is your padding method. It produces a string and   so you're getting a TypeError when you try to apply it to the plaintext, which should be bytes. You can fix this if you pad with bytes,

```
chunk += b' ' * (16 - len(chunk) % 16)
```

but it would be best to use the PKCS7 padding (currently you're using zero padding, but with a space instead of a zero byte).

PyCryptodome provides padding functions, but it seems you're using PyCrypto. In this case, you could implement PKCS7 padding, or better yet copy PyCryptodome's padding functions.

```
try:
    from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad, unpad
except ImportError:
    from Crypto.Util.py3compat import bchr, bord

    def pad(data_to_pad, block_size):
        padding_len = block_size-len(data_to_pad)%block_size
        padding = bchr(padding_len)*padding_len
        return data_to_pad + padding

    def unpad(padded_data, block_size):
        pdata_len = len(padded_data)
        if pdata_len % block_size:
            raise ValueError("Input data is not padded")
        padding_len = bord(padded_data[-1])
        if padding_len<1 or padding_len>min(block_size, pdata_len):
            raise ValueError("Padding is incorrect.")
        if padded_data[-padding_len:]!=bchr(padding_len)*padding_len:
            raise ValueError("PKCS#7 padding is incorrect.")
        return padded_data[:-padding_len]
```

The `pad` and `unpad` functions were copied from [`Crypto.Util.Padding`](https://github.com/Legrandin/pycryptodome/blob/master/lib/Crypto/Util/Padding.py) and modified to use only PKCS7 padding. Note that when using PKCS7 padding it is important to pad the last chunk, even if its size is a multiple of the block size, otherwise you won't be able to unpad correctly.

Applying those changes to the `encrypt_file` function,

```
def encrypt_file(key, in_filename, out_filename=None, chunksize=64*1024):
    if not out_filename:
        out_filename = in_filename + '.enc'
    iv = os.urandom(16)
    encryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    filesize = os.path.getsize(in_filename)
    with open(in_filename, 'rb') as infile:
        with open(out_filename, 'wb') as outfile:
            outfile.write(struct.pack('<Q', filesize))
            outfile.write(iv)
            pos = 0
            while pos < filesize:
                chunk = infile.read(chunksize)
                pos += len(chunk)
                if pos == filesize:
                    chunk = pad(chunk, AES.block_size)
                outfile.write(encryptor.encrypt(chunk))
```

and the matching `decrypt_file` function,

```
def decrypt_file(key, in_filename, out_filename=None, chunksize=64*1024):
    if not out_filename:
        out_filename = in_filename + '.dec'
    with open(in_filename, 'rb') as infile:
        filesize = struct.unpack('<Q', infile.read(8))[0]
        iv = infile.read(16)
        encryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        with open(out_filename, 'wb') as outfile:
            encrypted_filesize = os.path.getsize(in_filename)
            pos = 8 + 16 # the filesize and IV.
            while pos < encrypted_filesize:
                chunk = infile.read(chunksize)
                pos += len(chunk)
                chunk = encryptor.decrypt(chunk)
                if pos == encrypted_filesize:
                    chunk = unpad(chunk, AES.block_size)
                outfile.write(chunk)
```

This code is Python2/Python3 compatible, and it should work either with PyCryptodome or with PyCrypto.

However, if you're using PyCrypto, I recommend updating to PyCryptodome. PyCryptodome is a fork of PyCrypto and it exposes the same API (so you won't have to change your code too much), plus  some extra features: padding functions, Authenticated Encryption algorithms, KDFs etc. On the other hand, PyCrypto is not being maintained anymore and also, some versions suffer from a heap-based buffer overflow vulnerability: [CVE-2013-7459](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2013-7459).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the accepted answer, I believe showing multiple implementations of simple AES encryption can be useful for readers/new learners:

```
import os
import sys
import pickle
import base64
import hashlib
import errno

from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

DEFAULT_STORAGE_DIR = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '.ncrypt')

def create_dir(dir_name):
    """ Safely create a new directory. """
    try:
        os.makedirs(dir_name)
        return dir_name
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno != errno.EEXIST:
            raise OSError('Unable to create directory.')


class AESCipher(object):
    DEFAULT_CIPHER_PICKLE_FNAME = "cipher.pkl"

    def __init__(self, key):
        self.bs = 32  # block size
        self.key = hashlib.sha256(key.encode()).digest()

    def encrypt(self, raw):
        raw = self._pad(raw)
        iv = Random.new().read(AES. block_size)
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        return base64.b64encode(iv + cipher.encrypt(raw))

    def decrypt(self, enc):
        enc = base64.b64decode(enc)
        iv = enc[:AES.block_size]
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        return self._unpad(cipher.decrypt(enc[AES.block_size:])).decode('utf-8')

    def _pad(self, s):
        return s + (self.bs - len(s) % self.bs) * chr(self.bs - len(s) % self.bs)

    @staticmethod
    def _unpad(s):
        return s[:-ord(s[len(s)-1:])]
```

And illustrating examples of the above's usage:

```
while True:
    option = input('\n'.join(["="*80,
                              "| Select an operation:",
                              "| 1) E : Encrypt",
                              "| 2) D : Decrypt",
                              "| 3) H : Help",
                              "| 4) G : Generate new cipher",
                              "| 5) Q : Quit",
                              "="*80,
                              "> "])).lower()
    print()

    if option == 'e' or option == 1:
        plaintext = input('Enter plaintext to encrypt: ')
        print("Encrypted: {}".format(cipher.encrypt(plaintext).decode("utf-8")))

    elif option == 'd' or option == 2:
        ciphertext = input('Enter ciphertext to decrypt: ')
        print("Decrypted: {}".format(cipher.decrypt(ciphertext.encode("utf-8"))))

    elif option == 'h' or option == 3:
        print("Help:\n\tE: Encrypt plaintext\n\tD: Decrypt ciphertext.")

    elif option == 'g' or option == 4:
        if input("Are you sure? [yes/no]: ").lower() in ["yes", "y"]:
            cipher = AESCipher(key=input('Enter cipher password: '))

            with open(pickle_fname, 'wb') as f:
                pickle.dump(cipher, f)
            print("Generated new cipher.")

    elif option == 'q' or option == 5:
        raise EOFError
    else:
        print("Unknown operation.")
```

Comment: +1, nice class, but I'm afraid the title of this question won't attract many readers interested in Python encryption. Also, this will not work for larger files, you would have to 'cut' them to chunks, like the OP does.

Comment: I click on most of the Python-related featured questions, so maybe it attracts a few. :D Why would this not work for larger files?

Comment: Because you can't store several GB to a string, it would raise a MemoryError.

Comment: Chunking into multiple strings of size `max_length` is the solution? Or a stream from a file?

Comment: Yes, chunking works fine, as long as the chunk size is a multiple of the block size (only for CBC and ECB). The last chunk can be of any size, will be padded.

Comment: If you would like some tips, SHA256 is not suitable as a key derivation function, it's best to use `hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac` with a long, random salt (8 bytes minimum), and a high number of iterations (10,000 minimum). Also, you may want to HMAC the ciphertext, CBC can be vulnerable to padding oracle attacks, in some situations. I've written a Python class that covers all those issues, you can find it [here](https://github.com/tasos-py/AES-Encryption-Classes/blob/master/aes_encryption.py) if you want. Currently it uses only password-based keys, but I will update it soon.

Comment: @t.m.adam Thanks for the Python implementation, yours seems to have more features than mine! (and thanks for the MIT License...)

Comment: Glad you like it! I started this project a couple of years ago, when I had to port Python encryption code to PHP. Since then I improved the implementation and added more programing languages. The biggest problem was .NET because it has limited KDF options and it doesn't support any authenticated encryption algorithms so I had to use Encrypt-then-MAC. Feel free to criticize/contribute.